# How to visualize the Frobenius endomorphism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, visualization

As the question title asks for, how do others "visualize" the Frobenius endomorphism? I asked some people in real life and they said they didn't know and that I could go and ask on MO and possibly get miseducated. So that's what I am doing. Bonus points for pictures.

Comment: One possibility: Google for "primes and knots". (Imagine $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathcal{O}_K$ as a $3$-manifold and the primes as knots with the Frobenius as a generator of the étale fundamental group of the (residue field of the) prime ideals.)

Comment: A related analogy is that curves over finite fields are like 3-manifolds. More precisely, they are like the mapping torus associated to a Riemann surface equipped with an endomorphism.

Comment: The Frobenius is topologically an isomorphism with everywhere non reduced fibres. So maybe draw a thick line with an arrow down to a parallel thin line?

Comment: Personally, I do not visualize the Frobenius endomorphism.

Comment: here is a Christmas tree inspired visualisation: https://mathoverflow.net/a/117007/11260

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably the best way to think about the Frobenius morphism, and more generally purely inseparable finite morphisms of schemes, is as some sort of *foliation*. For example, Ekedahl proved the following result:

**Proposition** [Ek, **Prop. 2.4**]. *Let $Y$ be a smooth variety over a perfect field $k$ of characteristic $p > 0$. Then there is a $1$-$1$-correspondence between finite flat height $1$ purely inseparable morphisms $Y \to X$ to a smooth variety $X$ and subbundles $\mathscr E \subseteq \mathcal T_{Y/k}$ stable under Lie brackets and $p$-th powers, associating to $Y \to X$ the subbundle $\mathcal T_{Y/X} \subseteq \mathcal T_{Y/k}$.*

Here, a purely inseparable morphism $Y \to X$ has *height n*¹ if and only if there exists a morphism $X \to Y^{(p^n)}$ such that the composition $Y \to X \to Y^{(p^n)}$ is the $p^n$-th power relative Frobenius.

Among height $1$ morphisms, the Frobenius $Y \to Y^{(p)}$ is clearly terminal, hence corresponds to the subbundle $\mathcal T_{Y/k}$ (this is also clear from the description of the correspondence). If $Y$ is smooth of dimension $n$ over a perfect field $k$, then the fibres of relative Frobenius $F_{Y/k} \colon Y \to Y^{(p)}$ are isomorphic to the 'thick point' $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(x_1^p,\ldots,x_n^p)$.

**What does this look like?**

So we are to think of purely inseparable morphisms as 'infinitesimal foliations': they define a subbundle of the tangent bundle, and 'integrating' this subbundle should give the 'leaves' of the foliation. Here is a very crude picture:

[image: Infinitesimal foliation]

We see that the tangent space of the leaves is the entire space, and they form some sort of thick covering of $Y$, whose fibres are Artin local schemes of length $p^n$ (as above).

---

¹This seems to be standard terminology. If $Y \to X$ has height $n$, it also has height $m$ for any $m \geq n$. Probably a better definition would be that $Y \to X$ has *height $\leq n$*.

---

**References.**

[Ek]  Ekedahl, Torsten, *Foliations and inseparable morphisms*. In: [*Algebraic geometry, Proc. Summer Res. Inst., Brunswick/Maine 1985*, Part 2](https://doi.org/10.1090/pspum/046.2). Proc. Symp. Pure Math. 46, No. 2, 139-149 (1987). [ZBL0659.14018](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0659.14018).

Comment: What bothers me a bit with this picture is that it looks like $Y$ is not reduced, when it should be about the morphism being "strange" instead. Not that I have any better idea, though.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich: non-reducedness is at the essence of inseparable morphisms: the fibres are not geometrically reduced. But somehow they glue together into a total space that is reduced. Such is life in characteristic $p$.